# Not allowed to bind to service Intent - SpeechRecognizer

Tags: java, android-studio, google-api, speech-recognition

After Google did an update, my SpeechRecognizer no longer works on my Android 10 device.

There seems to be a problem with the permissions but also after adding both of the following lines, nothing changed.

> android:exported="true"
> android:process=":remote"

This is my Manifest

```
<queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.speech.RecognitionService"
                    android:process=":remote"
                    android:exported="true"/>

        </intent>
    </queries>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

This is the error-message

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to bind to service Intent { act=android.speech.RecognitionService cmp=com.samsung.android.bixby.agent/.mainui.voiceinteraction.MainVoiceInteractionService }
```

and here the line where the error occurs

```
speech.startListening(recognizerIntent);
```

Comment: Having the same problem with Nokia 5.4. Any progress on your end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I deinstalled google on my test device. Thie is why the app can`t use the google speech recognizer. The solution in this case is to install Google Chrome and activate their language package in the device settings.